# Meromorphic functions of non integral order

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

We know that an entire function of non integral order has infinitely many zeros. What can be said about the zeros and poles of a meromorphic function of non integral order? In fact, is there any representation of meromorphic functions of non integral order? 
The order of a meromorphic function is defined as
$\sigma=\displaystyle{\limsup\limits_{r\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\log T(r,f)}{\log r}}$, where $T(r,f)$ is the Nevanlinna characteristic function.

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings it would be helpful if you provide your definition of “order” for meromorphic functions.

Comment: I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch for the answer ([the lecture notes of Hayman has proofs)](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr17.pdf)- a good intuitive definition of the order of meromorphic functions is that if we write $f=g/h$, $g,h$ entire and "minimal" (no common factors), the order of $f$ is the maximum of the orders of $g,h$; rigorously we need to use the Nevalinna characteristic of course.

In particular, this immediately implies that a meromorphic function of non-integral order takes all but at most one values (including infinity) infinitely many times as either $g$ or $h$ must have non-integral order hence so does $g-ah$ for at most one finite $a$ and same for the poles of $f$ which are the zeroes of $h$.

We cannot in general do better as taking $(\cos \sqrt z)/z$ which has precisely one pole and non-integral order $1/2$ shows. Same for $(a\cos \sqrt z-1)/(\cos \sqrt z)$ and finite $a$

Comment: can a meromorphic function always be written as f=g/h for entire g, h? Also,  how is it different from the integral order case?  Please explain.

Comment: Also, please tell me where I can get a compact proof of the fact that if f=g/h, then order(f)=max{order(g),order(h)}.

Comment: look in the notes I linked as the rigorous proofs for order require the Nevalinna characteristic; as for meromorphic $f=g/h$ the plane - poles of $f$ do not accumulate at any finite value, so one can construct $h$ with zeroes at the poles of $f$ and of the same order; then $hf$ is entire; in the integral order case the exponential term can screw things up so something like $e^z/z$, for example, doesn't take either $0$ or $\infty$ infinitely many times, while in the order $0$ case rational functions take values only finitely many times

Comment: Thank you so much. I will definitely go through the lecture notes attached by you.

Comment: happy to be of help - intuitively things are failry clear but one has to be careful as poles distort growth near them (it is polynomial but still...), so that's why one needs the Nevanlinna characteristic in general rather than the usual $\max_{|z|=R}|f|$ for entire functions

Comment: Yes sir/ma'am, you are absolutely right